# insert a char between text in column dataframe

Tags: r

i want to insert a char between text in my df like this

```
df=data.frame(Clock=c("78","89","910","1011"))
```

| Clock |
| --- |
| 78 |
| 89 |
| 910 |
| 1011 |

my expected df

| Clock |
| --- |
| 0708 |
| 0809 |
| 0910 |
| 1011 |

Comment: `sprintf("%04d", ifelse(x < 100, (x %/% 10) * 100 + x %% 10, x))` maybe.  Not sure what you'd expect for values like `111` for example.

Comment: sorry, my df type is char
i tried using dplyr df[df=="78"]<-"0708" to the last, but it's not effectived

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strsplit()` into individual characters, insert `"0"`s conditional on vector length, then `paste()` back together:

```
df$Clock <- sapply(
  strsplit(df$Clock, split = ""),
  \(x) {
    if (length(x) == 2) {
      x <- append(x, "0", after = 1)
    }
    if (length(x) == 3) {
      x <- c("0", x)
    }
    paste(x, collapse = "")
  }
)

df
```

```
  Clock
1  0708
2  0809
3  0910
4  1011
```

Note @RitchieSacramento’s comment about ambiguous inputs like `"111"`. You could also use his solution by coercing to numeric first.